# greenlock-express for simple nodejs webapp

Tags: node.js, ssl, https, greenlock

I'm trying to setup HTTPS encryption for my nodejs webapp. From what I learned, **greenlock-express** (formely known as letsencrypt-express) is the easiest way to do it.

My app is pretty simple, but I'm having a hard time to follow the usage instructions from https://git.coolaj86.com/coolaj86/greenlock-express.js

This is the overall structure of the files:

```
.
|-- app.json
|-- index.js
|-- node_modules
|-- package.json
|-- Procfile
|-- public
|-- README.md
`-- views
```

This is the index.js:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.set('port', (process.env.PORT || 5000));

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

// views is directory for all template files
app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

app.get('/', function(request, response) {
  response.render('pages/index');
});

app.listen(app.get('port'), function() {
  console.log('Node app is running on port', app.get('port'));
});
```

How should I proceed?

Comment: I'm struggling with the same. From the instructions, I thought I could wrap the express application inside the greenlock-express thingy - but that just makes my app disappear. I wonder if greenlock-express isn't a wrapper for https from where I can stuff my ExpressJS app - but instead an agent for updating certificates. If so, this must run side by side with my app. I wish somebody with more knowledge would answer.

Comment: seems like `greenlock-express` is crap

Answer (score 2):

## v2, Video Tutorial, Updated Documentation

**First**, make sure you're using the latest version (v2) of Greenlock™.

https://git.coolaj86.com/coolaj86/greenlock-express.js

There's a short, easy-to-follow video tutorial as well as a simple but thorough troubleshooting section (also explained over in the video).

**Second**, all you need to do is to NOT use express' `app.listen()` and instead pass your app to Greenlock:

### index.js:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.set('port', (process.env.PORT || 5000));

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

// views is directory for all template files
app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

app.get('/', function(request, response) {
  response.render('pages/index');
});

//app.listen(app.get('port'), function() {
//  console.log('Node app is running on port', app.get('port'));
//});
module.exports = app;
```

### greenlock-app.js:

```
'use strict';

var homedir = require('path').join(require('os').homedir();
require('greenlock-express').create({

  version: 'draft-11'
, server: 'https://acme-staging-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory'  // staging
, email: 'john.doe@example.com'                                     // CHANGE THIS
, agreeTos: true
, approveDomains: [ 'example.com', 'www.example.com' ]              // CHANGE THIS
, configDir: homedir, 'acme', 'etc')

//, app: require('express')().use('/', function (req, res) {
//    res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/html; charset=utf-8')
//    res.end('Hello, World!\n\n .js');
//  })

app: require('./index.js')

, communityMember: true
//, debug: true
}).listen(80, 443);
```